# mongodb create the index to only the first item in array

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a json input like:

```
        {
            "Wells": {
               "mywell 1": {
                 "X": 0,
                 "Y": 0,
                 "Tags": {
                   "READING": [
                      {
                         "Time": "11/13/2017 9:54:59 AM",
                         "Value": 959.9707
                       }
                   ]
                }
              }
            },
            "Errors": []
        }
```

that i am loading into mongodb via pymongo. I am trying to set the index for the first item in Wells. So in this case it would be "mywell 1"

I thought perhaps

```
db.log_events.ensureIndex( { Wells.[0]: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

or something similar, so each well would only be entered once. Does anyone know how to set the index to only the first item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only index static document keys, so you can't do what you're asking.

Instead, change the schema of your document so that `Wells` is an array (it's currently an object) and move your dynamic `"mywell 1"` key into a `name` property of your array elements:

```
"Wells": [
 {
   "name": "mywell 1",
   "X": 0,
   "Y": 0,
   "Tags": {
     "READING": [
        {
           "Time": "11/13/2017 9:54:59 AM",
           "Value": 959.9707
         }
     ]
   }
 }]
```

With the document restructured, you can now add an index on `Wells.name`, letting you efficiently query by well name.

```
db.log_events.ensureIndex({ 'Wells.name': 1 })
```

Comment: That's actually what i was thinking after reading through a bunch of docs, but i'm new to mongo and figured maybe there was something i was missing. thanks